# Why does this code not place newly added controls away from the textblock?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to programatically create an image, set its width and height to a random integer,
add it to my canvas and run a check to see if a rectangle with the same specs (x, y, size)
intersects a textblock in the middle of my screen. If so, the void function uses a goto statement named "try_again" to go to a previous line until it successfully generates the image away from the textblock. The only problem is, the Rect.Intersect is supposed to show a non empty rectangle in the case where there is an intersection and the empty rectangle (Rect.Empty) otherwise, but it doesn't.
Any feedback is appreciated. Here :

```
        public void add_mini_star()
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.Image mini_star =
                new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            mini_star.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri
                    (@"/Star.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            mini_star.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        try_again:

            var star_size = rnd.Next(10, 40);
            mini_star.Width = star_size;
            mini_star.Height = star_size;

            Canvas.SetLeft(mini_star, rnd.Next(0, (int)(900 - star_size)));
            Canvas.SetTop(mini_star, rnd.Next(0, (int)(700 - star_size)));
            ___Canvas1_.Children.Add(mini_star);

            mini_star.Opacity = 0;

            Rect mini_star_rect = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(mini_star), Canvas.GetTop(mini_star),
                mini_star.Width, mini_star.Height);


            Rect textblock_rect = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(textBlock1), Canvas.GetTop(textBlock1),
                textBlock1.ActualWidth, textBlock1.ActualHeight);

            if (System.Windows.Rect.Intersect(mini_star_rect, textblock_rect) != Rect.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("problem"); // Never Fires =(
                ___Canvas1_.Children.Remove(mini_star);
                goto try_again;
            }

            mini_stars.Add(mini_star);
        }

        private void window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            sb1 = (Storyboard)FindResource("Storyboard1"); // Storyboard for other animations.

            for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++) // Where it adds the mini star image.
            {
                add_mini_star();
            }

            DoubleAnimation[] start_anims = new DoubleAnimation[32];

            for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++)
            {
                start_anims[x] = new DoubleAnimation();
                start_anims[x].From = 0;
                start_anims[x].To = 1;
                start_anims[x].Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
                start_anims[x].BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4);

                start_anims[x].FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
                start_anims[x].Completed += new
                    EventHandler(OnCompleted); // works already (fades out stars after showing).


                mini_stars[x].BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, start_anims[x]);
                
                // below line does not work, OnCompleted begins second animation to fade stars out.
                //mini_stars[x].BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, finish_anims[x]);
            }

            sb1.Begin();
        }
```

I honestly have been fiddling with this code for a while now, yet still can't seem to find a clue as to what might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Programatically creating a textBlock to replace the textBlock created through xaml design seemed to fix the problem. Probably some properties were changed that I forgot about like the transform property instead of the Left and Top properties.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).